# can I create top level instance in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin, instance

If I have app.kt file in kotlin, can I create instance like `appKt()`? Thanks.
Kotlin has top level function. For example I can write in app.kt:

```
val a = 123
fun abc() {}
appKt.abc()
```

my question is if I can create appKt instance and call instance method

Answer (score 0):

Only classes can be instanced.

Instead of loose function `fun abc() {}`, this should be the method of a class:

```
class appKt() {
    // private var a: Integer = 123
    fun abc() {}
}
```

Comment: Unlike Java, Kotlin does allow [top-level functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#function-scope).

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't put arbitrary code at the top level.

You can put only definitions of classes (just as in Java), [objects](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-declarations-overview), [functions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/functions.html#function-scope), and [properties](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/properties.html).

It wouldn't make much sense to put loose code there, anyway: when would it run?

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve with this. If you want some code that gets run when your program starts up, then you could put it into a top-level function — but you'd then have to *call* that function (e.g. from your `main()` method). Or you could put it in the `init` block of the companion object to a class that you know will be loaded. Or if you're using a framework such as Android or Spring, then that will probably provide ways to specify code to be run at start-up.